# Why are this many bytes written to the standard output device?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, real-mode

I have the following data declarations, and the data segment and code segment registers are all correctly initialized:

```
d1  db 1,2
d2  dw 3
d3  db 'ABC'
d4  db 'DE'
d5  db 'F'
d6  db '$'
```

I run this set of instructions on DOSbox:

```
mov dx, offset d2
add dx, 2
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

Why is that the standard output device would write 6 bytes? I understand that d2 is a word, so it is 2 bytes of data. But I do not completely understand why there would be an output for 6 bytes?

Comment: `mov dx, offset d2 + 2` would be more efficient: make the assembler add at build time instead of emitting an instruction to add at runtime.  Anyway, with that add, you're passing a pointer to the end of `d2` so its size is irrelevant to what the string-output DOS function does.

Comment: FWIW, `mov dx,offset d2+2` is equivalent to `mov dx,offset d3` in the code above. And `db 'ABC'; db 'DE'; db 'F'; db '$'` (<-- where ; is newline) is equivalent to `db 'ABCDEF$'`, as they are all consecutive bytes in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code:

```
mov dx, offset d2
add dx, 2
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

does the same as:

```
mov dx, offset d3 ; offset d3 equals offset d2 + 2, because d2 is a word.
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

The several data instructions `db` produce consecutive bytes in memory (here), so this:

```
d3  db 'ABC'
d4  db 'DE'
d5  db 'F'
d6  db '$'
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
d3  db 'ABCDEF$' ; assuming you don't need labels d4, d5, d6 somewhere else
```

So you are passing the string `'ABCDEF$'` to `int 21h`, function `AH=9`, ["Display string"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_API#DOS_INT_21h_services), and that prints all characters of the string you pass in `DX`, up to the final `'$'`. So it prints

```
ABCDEF
```

as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You move the offset of `d2` into *DX*. That points at the two bytes starting at `dw 3`. 2 is then added to *DX*, thus *DX* now points just past the 2 byte word which happens to be the start of `d3`. [Int 21/ah=9](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) will print characters up to (and not including the `$`) starting at the offset in *DX*. The characters starting at offset `d3` (and ending at the `$`) should be printed. That output should be `ABCDEF` which are the 6 characters you should have seen displayed.